# Can I string ethernet cables?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cabling

Is it possible to string Ethernet male-to-female cables?

I have a cable I need to extend, but it's in the wall, so I can't just replace it with a longer one. It has no connectors yet, so I'm thinking I could fit one end with female, making it a male/female cable. Into this I would plug in the extending male/male cable. Will this work?

I know about Ethernet couplers, and that's certainly an option, but I'm considering the alternative, since I have yet to crimp on the connectors.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your scenario, that's essentially what an Ethernet wall plate is...the Ethernet cable runs from a switch to a wall plate (female), then you plug in a male-to-male cable to basically "extend" (aka "patch") the cable from the wall plate to your computer. All that matters is that the wire sequence is correct

Comment: @wysiwyg exactly. Instead of a female connection from a wall plate, he'll have a female connection from a cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. This will work.

You just need to match the wiring at both ends, so T568A or T568B.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about a splice and yes your male female ending will work but keep in mind each one is a point of fail and source to add noise to the line. Make sure you keep the color codes correct and standard. Putting a splice in like that is not a proper code approved cable run so if that is an issue you might want to look at my next suggestion. Another solution would be to use the already run line as a line to pull a new longer single cable through the conduit if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I know about Ethernet couplers, and that's certainly an option, but I'm considering >the alternative, since I have yet to crimp on the connectors.

Not sure why you think you would need to crimp the cables...I have seen ethernet female-to-female couplers so all you would need is another ethernet cable. Of course, not the most elegant way of doing it but this will get you going as long as you are within the ethernet range limits.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer, right? What I meant was this: the cable which is already in the wall has no connectors yet. Thus, "I have yet to crimp on the connectors" to it, and I can as well crimp on a female.

Comment: @sferencik you could, however the defacto standard is that for Ethernet the cables are male, which will make it difficult to keep compatible if you ever need to replace it or make it work with another cable you bought from somewhere, as cables with a female end for Ethernet are quite rare